# How to get notified on "mute" when app is written using ClutterGstPlayback

Tags: gstreamer, clutter

I have written an audio application using **ClutterGstPlayback** object. I want my application to get notified whenever my application is muted (app could be muted by audio-manager). My use-case is to pause the app whenever it is muted and play it again later.
FYI, ClutterGstPlayback implements CluttGstPlayer interface, I could not find any property or signal which is emitted when app is muted. **Could you please tell me how to get notified whenever App is muted?**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how is the clutter implemented, but if it uses pulsesink you can patch it to emit application tag on which you can react.

That is go to gst_pulsesink_set_mute implementation and add there:

```
GstStructure *str = gst_structure_new("custom_muted", 
    "muted", G_TYPE_BOOLEAN, mute, NULL);
GstMessage *msg = gst_message_new_application(GST_OBJECT(psink), str);
if (!gst_element_post_message(psink, msg)) {
    fail..
}
```

Then in your bus watch you react on GST_MESSAGE_APPLICATION and catch it:

```
if (gst_message_has_name(p_msg, "custom_muted")) {
    gboolean muted;
    const GstStructure *str = gst_message_get_structure(p_msg);
    gst_structure_get_boolean(str, "muted", &muted);
    if (muted)
         do_my_fancy_pause();
}
```

Comment: [ClutterGstPlayback](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter-gst/stable/ClutterGstPlayback.html) internally uses playbin for playing audio. [Playbin](https://developer.gnome.org/gst-plugins-libs/stable/gst-plugins-base-plugins-playbin.html#GstPlayBin--uri) uses autoaudiosink. So we cannot always assume it will use pulsesink.

Comment: @AkashJain well you can specify [audio-sink](https://developer.gnome.org/gst-plugins-libs/stable/gst-plugins-base-plugins-playbin.html#GstPlayBin--audio-sink) to be pulseaudio ..